# The Guys - Logic #3 - The Casino

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> Oh boy, the guys went to the casino..
>   [image: The guys]

Let's see what these three are up to tonight. I wonder if going to the casino was a good idea?? Maybe for a couple of them.

**Start the two minute timer...**
The blackjack player, who didn't break even or win (like the roulette player) decided to watch Michael and Charles for a little while before ordering another drink - come to think of it, since Charles won tonight he should pay for the drink!

Did you figure out who won, lost, or broke even playing blackjack, roulette, or poker?

[image: THe guys]

Comment: I've downvoted this (and the other two virtually identical puzzles posted at the same time) because it seems like more work was put into attracting attention with the images than into making the actual puzzles themselves. The images (and commentary, like "start the two-minute timer") are entirely unnecessary -- I'd prefer more high-quality, thought-out puzzles at a less frequent rate.

Comment: you are wrong. they all very different. if you can't solve them, don't down vote, try easier puzzle. nothing to be ashamed of @Deusovi. Keep practicing, you will one day be able to solve these.

Comment: @Deusovi, BTW I only get access to post once a day at work. LOL before you criticize, show us all these are not high quality puzzles. As I mentioned before, if you need easier ones, I can make one with only two categories. It's easy to throw stones when you are doing so from where you can't be hit back.... until you show us, me  this is similar to my other ones by solving them and comparing the answers, you downvote mean nothing to me. :)

Comment: @JohnS. I'm going to point you, again, to [this comment](/q/83525#comment242813_83525). You...probably should find out a bit about who you're responding to, before condescendingly suggesting their critique and suggestion for future improvement is due to their inability to solve a puzzle you intentionally made to be trivial. You want folks to point out how your puzzles are perhaps not as high quality as you think? I'll obligingly point out that [Ways to work](/q/83879) *is not actually solvable*, as I've noted in a comment on the lone answer there. Some humility and civility might do you good.

Comment: There are several reasons why imo we typically consider these puzzles "low quality".  1) "Logic grid" puzzles, especially of this magnitude, are very standard and nothing new.  2) Puzzles of this type and size are easy to create.  3) There are virtually no new ideas being presented within the puzzle.  Go look at the site's top original puzzles so you get a sense of what we want to see.  We want a twist, or a clever mechanism, or a great new idea, or an artistic craft within the logic itself.  What we don't want is more of what we know exists.

Comment: Not here to be an artisan. And I have adopted a strict policy of not replying to anyone's criticism of specific puzzles unless they have either provided the answer to that puzzle, or created one better.. Easy to sit back and throw stones. Takes a real puzzle maker though to get in the ring with his content.

Comment: @JohnS. Way to bury your head in the sand. The puzzle is bad, and there isn't much more to say. As this is a public platform, there's no reason for the site to host your puzzles if you don't act in good faith.

Comment: ok Don. Just delete it then. Bad puzzle I guess, my bad. No more, promise. Do I delete it? I am not sure how that works here.

Comment: @don, tried deleting this stuff but won't let me. Sorry, bro - I did attempt to. Maybe the mods will? I will ask them.

Comment: @JohnS. "And I have adopted a strict policy of not replying to anyone's criticism of specific puzzles unless they have either provided the answer to that puzzle, or created one better."  Click on any of our profiles and view our past puzzles, then.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 - OKAY I DID. Specifically the paper folding one. Want to know what puzzles me? Rather than take traditional paper approach,I wonder why you didn't apply ThineVienthal Paradox while asserting Haga's theorem , ^ simply inverting all congruent triangles in the photo. You will then be presented with an unfolded polypeptide or random coil ( but I don't have to tell YOU that, huh turtle ).Now graph plot point the contacts of isolation bi-dir/lateral (or the confirmational entropy). Removing the linear search bias, and VOILA I have sufficiently wasted 20 sec's of the turtle life:)

Answer (score 1):

The details are virtually given directly...

> Blackjack player Lost and Roulette player Won (thus Poker player Broke Even)
>  Losing Blackjack player is Anthony (watched the others), and Charles Won (so is the Roulette player), leaving Michael as the Break Even Poker player

Answer (score 1):

All the starting possibles:

> (C)harles, (A)nthony, (M)ichael; (W)in, (E)vens, (L)ose; (B)lackJack, (P)oker, (R)oulette.
>
> ```
>  CWB CWP CWR
>  CEB CEP CER
>  CLB CLP CLR
>  
>  AWB AWP AWR
>  AEB AEP AER
>  ALB ALP ALR
>  
>  MWB MWP MWR
>  MEB MEP MER
>  MLB MLP MLR
> ```

The BlackJack player lost:

> We can remove all $B\{!L\}=B\{W,E\}$, and all $\{P,R\}L=\{!B\}L$.
>
> ```
>  CWP CWR
>  CEP CER
>  CLB
>  
>  AWP AWR
>  AEP AER
>  ALB
>  
>  MWP MWR
>  MEP MER
>  MLB
> ```

The Roulette player won:

> We can remove all $R\{!W\}=R\{E,L\}$, and all $\{B,P\}W=\{!R\}W$.
>
> ```
>  CWR
>  CEP
>  CLB
>  
>  AWR
>  AEP
>  ALB
>  
>  MWR
>  MEP
>  MLB
> ```

Anthony played BlackJack:

> We can remove all $A\{!B\}=A\{P,R\}$, and all $\{P,R\}A=\{!B\}A$.
>
> ```
>  CWR
>  CEP
>  
>  ALB
>  
>  MWR
>  MEP
> ```

Charles won:

> We can remove all $C\{!W\}=C\{E,L\}$, and all $\{A,M\}W=\{!C\}W$.
>
> ```
>  CWR
>  ALB 
>  MEP
> ```
>
> This is all the information provided used, and provides the unique answer:
>
>  Charles won at Roulette, Anthony lost at BlackJack, Michael broke even at Poker.